# Are you clever enough?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I'm always in your thoughts, technically twice
 
If displayed correctly, just to be precise

If you see my left you will call me a con
and it would tear me apart if you called me John

Take down a note and drop your cup
All you need is what keeps up

Please don't apply pressure or I will be off
and try to solve my riddle if you can take the scoff

---

Don't you dare look at the solution below.

> Shame upon you! Try harder. 
>  The solution is a single, short word. This won't help you for now but "meow"

Comment: Darnit, breaking my neck over this for the last 30 min. Whole company of 20 men is thinking about this now...

Comment: I appreciate your commitment!

Comment: Brilliant question

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Perhaps the single short word is the word "on"
>  
>  It appears in "your" and "thoughts" if thoughts is viewed upside down
>  and reflected.
>  
>  To make the word John, you have to split the o and the n, thus
>  tearing him up.
>  
>  If you "c" the left, you will now be "con", a con.
>  
>  If a switch is "on" and you apply pressure, it is now "off".

Comment: Unless you also reflect it, 'ou' shows up as 'no' upside down, not 'on'. But I can't see why it would be upside down and reflected if "displayed correctly".

Comment: Dat is wel heel erg vergezocht!

Comment: @Geobits, by "displayed correctly" he means displayed in the right way to see him.  He doesn't mean displayed in the conventional writing format.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I kinda like this answer. I went down this road, but the only clues I could get it to fit were con/John. None of the others make much sense IMO.

Comment: if you could hide your answer I would be very grateful. It is the correct answer :)

Comment: Maybe the question would work better if it said something like `I'm always in your thoughts, technically twice // 
If you reflect on it deeply, while being precise`. I don't yet see how the note - cup - keeps up bit is related.

Comment: It's funny because the first comment on this pointed out that the cup actually means "tea". So when you take down "a note" and remove "t" "e" and "a" all that's remaining is "no" again.

Answer (score 11):

The original answer is quite brilliant and exciting, but in my pursuit for finding it, I've stumbled upon a rather strange alternative which *seems to fit* the riddle. Have a look  at my **intentionally forced theory** and give me your opinion.

> Sherlock Holmes speaking to Professor Moriarty near the Reichenbach falls

Why? Well, read on if you are interested.

> I'm always in your thoughts, technically twice
>   If displayed correctly, just to be precise

Holmes was always a stinging thought in Moriarty's mind. The professor was directly involved in two cases titled "The Valley of Fear" and "The Final Problem". Hence Holmes would've crossed his mind twice.

> If you see my left you will call me a con
>   and it would tear me apart if you called me John

Holmes have said Watson about this once. "If you would've seen my sinister (left) side, You'd know that I make a perfect villain (con)". Also, since Holmes is speaking to Moriarty we could assume the second sentence is about (Dr.) John (Watson).

> Take down a note and drop your cup
>   All you need is what keeps up

The *note* might be referring to the one Holmes wrote to Watson moments before the death of his arch-enemy. Since the combat was done without any ammunition, Moriarty might be saying "All you need (for this final battle) is what keeps up (the strength of his body)

> Please don't apply pressure or I will be off
>   and try to solve my riddle if you can take the scoff

Moriarty's final words perhaps? He might be inches away from slipping off the ledge. "Do not apply the pressure (spare me Holmes)". Since his right-hand, Sebastian Moran, was still living to complete his mission, the professor shouts "solve my riddle if you can take the scoff" (which is impossible, my organization is bigger than you think, Holmes...)

Comment: I think it's fascinating what riddles do with people's minds. Your story actually kind of fits in here what's terrifying in a good way. Even after looking at the details your assumption still sounds plausible. Providing that your sources are reliable.

Answer (score 7):

Now this may sound crude and probably not the best answer but if looked at correctly in your mind theres 2 of them.

The con bit is the bit that is confusing there could be a link im not picking up on

No one wants to be called john if they have them? culture permitting.

no one wants to have heavy preasure on them no?

> take a note and drop a a cup.. Size??
> all you need is what keeps up ... Bra??
> and again correct me if im wrong but no one wants to have heavy preasure on boobs no?
>  boobs

Comment: "Don't you dare look at the solution below." ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about this, but it's not a short word and it doesn't fit all the clues.

> consciousness

Explanation:

> Your consciousness is on your thoughts,
>  the left part of the word is 'con',
>  John Searle is a philosopher who examined it.

Answer (score 3):

> the answer is "on" :) if you flip "your" and "thoughs" vertically, and if you press (apply pressure on a switch) it will become OFF :)

P.S. just saw someone answered it :) And yet I'm not a cheater, I just had a logo with ou/no for one of my projects, and I recognized it in "your thoughts" :)

Comment: Good job there tho!

Answer (score 2):

> I thought the word you be looking for is 'tea' but I'm not quite sure if it fits all clues. The letter 't' is twice in thoughts. And you drink tea from a cup so if you drop the cup tou are left with 'tea'.

Comment: You seem to be clever enough, although that's not the solution.

Comment: Same, I was trying to think if there was an A Team episode where Mr T. got angry at being called John...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

> Brain

Why:

> It is where thoughts are made, technically twice because it has two lobes, and John Braine is a novelist