# I'm found in a gong

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I'm found in a gong,
>   I look the same from both ends.
>   Now don't get me wrong:
>   Two straight and three bends.
>
> I'm a form of a word,
>   But not the one you're used to.
>   You know, I'm my third,
>   You'll find me if you choose to.

What am I?

Hint 1 (concerning some of the lines):

> Lines 3 and 8 are just flavour text, mainly included to fit the rhyme. Don't think too hard about them.

Hint 2 (concerning tags):

> This puzzle could also be tagged [letters] and [wordplay].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> The word "going".

I'm found in a gong,
I look the same from both ends.

> You get "going" from finding an "i" in "gong", and the word starts and ends with a "g" (not quite a palindrome but oh well)

Now don't get me wrong:
Two straight and three bends.

> Written in caps, the letters G, O, and G are bendy (3 of them) while I and N are straight

I'm a form of a word,
But not the one you're used to.

> Not too sure about this part

You know, I'm my third,

> "I" is the third letter of the word "going"

You'll find me if you choose to.

Comment: This is the correct answer ... but [user_MK found](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/46188/5373) that word already, despite thinking the solution was a letter instead of a word. I'm not sure if I should just award you the tick or encourage user_MK to edit their answer so I can award it to them.

Comment: @randal'thor How does _going_ look the same from both ends? And what form of a verb are we “used to”? I don’t get how this can be the correct answer…

Comment: @Janus "going" looks the same from both ends because both its ends are the same (G). It's not the standard form of the verb "go", the form we'd look up in the dictionary - instead it's the conjugated progressive form "going".

Comment: @randal'thor: I think the tick should go to user_MK. I hadn't read through all the answers before posting, and now that I saw his I think mine was quite a duplicate. Thanks though!

Comment: @Xenocacia I accepted your answer because the explanation is better, but I may award a bounty to user_MK just to balance things out.

Answer (score 8):

Is the word -

> non

I'm found in a gong,

> g**on**g Letters ***o*** and ***n*** and make **non**

I look the same from both ends.

> non is a palindrome and will be same if reversed.

Now don't get me wrong:

> non expresses negation hence ***wrong***.

Two straight and three bends.

> non has 2 straight lines in two n's and three bends in n(2) and o(1)
>  [image]

I'm a form of a word,
But not the one you're used to.

> We are not used to listen a "no" from anyone :)

You know, I'm my third,
You'll find me if you choose to.

> This might be a little tricky. So here's my take - "I'm my third" might relate to third letter of ra**n**d al'thor which is "n" and "You'll find me if you choose to." might relate to "You'll find me if you choose **two**" hence 2 n's.

Comment: Also, _non_ is the French form of ‘no’, which is presumably not the one most of us are used to hearing.

Comment: Nope, but good try. (And once again, I'm not enough of an egomaniac to write puzzles around my own name! :-P ) I'll add a hint.

Answer (score 7):

Is it

> The i in "going"?

I'm found in a gong

> i is in between the word gong

I look the same from both ends

> I is symmetrical or going has 'g' on both ends

Now don't get me wrong:
Two straight and three bends.

> Maybe describing the word "GOING" 'I' and 'N' are the 2 straight, 'G', 'O', 'G' are the 3 bends? This one I'm not sure of.

I'm a form of a word,
But not the one you're used to.

> i vs eye

You know, I'm my third,
You'll find me if you choose to.

> I is the third letter in 'going' or maybe that 'I'  is 1/3 of the total without the top and bottom lines

Edit: Ah it is the *word*

> going

Comment: This is VERY close to the correct answer. Try making the solution a word instead of a letter - it should then fit everything.

Answer (score 5):

Updated after latest hint:

Are you a

> SPACE (character)?

I'm found in a gong,

> The second character in the string "a gong" is a space. Gong would be a distractor in this case, as it could be literally any word.

I look the same from both ends.

> A space is blank; it looks the same (empty) from all directions.

Now don't get me wrong (ignored)
Two straight and three bends.

> In capital letters, AE are all straight lines (two straight) while SPC all have curves (three bends).

I'm a form of a word,
But not the one you're used to.

> Could mean a couple of things; spaces define words by being the borders, or in computer science, each character (including "space") can be represented by a "word" or set of bits.

You know, I'm my third,

> The third character in "my third" is also a space.

You'll find me if you choose to (ignored).

---

*Original try below...*
Are you a

> Tone?

I'm found in a gong,

> When you hit a gong, a tone is played.

I look the same from both ends.

> Tones are periodic, so when plotted as a function of time they look the same forward and backward.

Now don't get me wrong (ignored)
Two straight and three bends.

> Depending on the font/handwriting, "t" is written with two straight lines, and "one" can each be written as a single curved line.

I'm a form of a word,

> Tonal languages use tone to convey meaning

But not the one you're used to.

> English isn't a tonal language, and English-language speakers find tonal languages difficult to learn and understand.

You know, I'm my third,

> In music, "tone" is another word for a diminished third interval.

You'll find me if you choose to (ignored).

Comment: Sorry, nope. See new hint (I'll edit those tags in as actual tags if you feel the question is too broad without them).

Comment: Alright, I gave it another try following the hints.  I'm not sure this totally fits one of the "tags" though...

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> The word 'on'?

I'm found in a gong,

> g**on**g

I look the same from both ends.

> If you looked at it side-on or even top and bottom-on, then it would look the same

Now don't get me wrong:

> wr**on**g

Two straight and three bends.

> Made up of two straight lines and a bend in the 'n' and two bends in the 'o' (though that could be one bend)

I'm a form of a word,
But not the one you're used to.

> It starts off **on**e

You know, I'm my third,

> Not sure, maybe [Three on a match?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_on_a_match_(superstition))

You'll find me if you choose to.

> Turned on?

Comment: Nah, I leave riddles with this solution to [another puzzler](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4247/5373) ;-) Your explanations for lines 4-8 are a bit weak - the intended answer fits much better.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Onomatopoeia

I'm found in a gong

> "Gong" is an onomatopoeia because the word sounds like the sound a gong makes.

I look the same from both ends

> The word looks the same side-on from both ends.

Now don't get me wrong

> Onomatopoeia is frequently spelled incorrectly.

Two straight and Three Bends

> Onomatopoeia contains two "straight" letters (t and p) and three "bend" letters (o, a and e).

I'm a form of a word

> Onomatopoeia is a type of word

But not one you're used to

> It's not a very well known type of word

You know, I'm my third

> The number of letters (12) is divisible by three.

You'll find me if you choose to

> You can make up an onomatopoeic word based on a sound you hear.

Comment: Maybe I'm my third means that the third letter is the same as the one the starts the word.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I don't understand your answers to lines 2, 4, and 7 ... which might suggest that your answer isn't right :-) Good try though!

Answer (score 1):

My take

> Gun

I'm found in a gong,

> Gong originated from the Malay word gung, which contains gun

I look the same from both ends.
Now don't get me wrong:

> 'u' and 'n' are actually interchanged if you look upside down.

Two straight and three bends.

> One bend each of "g", "u" and "n" and a straight each of "n" and "u"

I'm a form of a word,
But not the one you're used to.

> People are not usually used to guns unless they are undercover agents or cops

You know, I'm my third,
You'll find me if you choose to

> Gun constitutes 3/4th of "Gung" or gong.

Comment: Line 1 actually has a more direct explanation (although yours is plausible). Your explanations of lines 2 and 5 aren't very convincing though ...

Answer (score 1):

Because there's substantial history and numerical relationships with it, but personally being unable to fit all the clues, I'm going to say:

> noon

I'm found in a gong,

> True: g**ON**g

I look the same from both ends.

> It's a palindrome.

Now don't get me wrong:

> Flavor text, but could relate also to time or getting the time wrong.

Two straight and three bends.

> At noon (or midnight in archaic definitions) the clock's minute and hour hands are both straight. Three bends? Not sure.

I'm a form of a word,

> It's a shortened form of afternoon, high-noon and others.

But not the one you're used to.

> Unfortunately for my purpose, it's a very common word.

You know, I'm my third,

> I'm thinking there might be some numerical significance to noon, 12, 3, and more:
>
>  dictionary.com: Old English nōn, from Latin nōna (hōra) ninth hour (originally 3 p.m., the ninth hour from sunrise)
>
>  Word Origin and History for noon
>  n. mid-12c., non "midday, 12 o'clock p.m., midday meal," from Old English non "**3 o'clock p.m.**, the ninth hour," also "the canonical hour of nones," from Latin nona hora "ninth hour" of daylight, by **Roman reckoning about 3 p.m.**, from nona, fem. singular of nonus "ninth" (see nones ). Sense shift from **"3 p.m."** to "12 p.m." began during 12c., when time of Church prayers shifted from ninth hour to sixth hour, or perhaps because the customary time of the midday meal shifted, or both. The shift was complete by 14c. (cf. same evolution in Dutch noen).

You'll find me if you choose to.

> 

Comment: Only half of this word is found in a gong.

Comment: @randal'thor, Hmmm... I see. So, I'm thinking it needs to be _wholly_ within it. And presumably none apart from it.

Comment: *struggling to restrain myself from giving out another clue*

Answer (score 1):

Am I:

> ag / silver

I'm found in a gong,

> ag is the first two letters of 'a gong' / Silver gongs exist (note it doesn't say all gongs)

I look the same from both ends.

> In certain fonts, a and g look like each other upside down, so I look the same from both ends could refer to the a and g at either end looking the same / ag is silver, and ga is gallium, both silver-coloured metals

Now don't get me wrong:
Two straight and three bends.

> ag has a bend on the left of the a, a straight on the right of the a, two bends on the left of the g and a straight on the right of the g \ Silver has two straight letters - il, three bend letters - ser and one that isn't bendy or straight... (v)

I'm a form of a word,
But not the one you're used to.

> ag is a form of silver, but not the one you'd necessarily expect unless you are a chemist/physicist or some such

You know, I'm my third,

> Silver is for second, but it's a third of the medal winners

You'll find me if you choose to.

> Flavour text fluff to make it rhyme (like line 3)

The answer is definitely not the best, but some of the things look too coincidental.

Comment: +1 I was thinking seriously about ag and ga too. But haven't had the time to formulate a proper answer yet.(Side effect of puzzling while on the job >.>) Good job

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's my best guess:

> sins

I'm found in a gong,
I look the same from both ends.

> It has the same first and last letter, like *gong*

Now don't get me wrong:

> *wrong*

Two straight and three bends.

> *Sins* has three bends and two straight lines in the letters

I'm a form of a word,
But not the one you're used to.

> This is where I start to doubt myself.
>  Sins is normally used in the singular form, as *sin*.
>  Instead of the noun-singular form (*one*), though, it's the verbal form.
>  "He sins"

You know, I'm my third,
You'll find me if you choose to.

> "Sins" is the third-person form of the verb.

I know it's a huge stretch but it's the best I can come up with.

Comment: Sorry, nope. The explanation for the first line is much more direct than this - not just any word with the same first and last letter would match.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> gag

- It's found in "a gong"
- It's a palindrome
- Two straight and three bends

> I'm not sure how it fits this criteria

- It's a synonym for

> a joke

- letters 1 and 3 are the same

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> A sound wave

Because

I'm found in a gong,

> The sound wave is the sound from gong.

I look the same from both sides.

> A sound wave may be symmetrical. Two straight and three bends. At the top and bottom (2) of a wave they may be considered flat or parallel to what is flat. Two "s" curves that share a point could be three curves.

I'm a form of a word,

> Sound waves are the form of words.

But not the one you're used to.

> We don't actively speak sound waves but do it unintentionally

You know, I'm my third,

> Third related to pi?

Comment: "Two straight and three bends" is more precise than that - it's *exactly* two and three. I just edited the question with a new hint.